# How to make DecoratedTabPanel border disappear?

Tags: gwt

I wanna use DecoratedTabPanel to store html. but the html container has border, so how to remove them ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DecoratedTabPanel dtp = new DecoratedTabPanel();
dtp.getDeckPanel().getElement().getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.NONE);
```